# How to update steam from command line?

Tags: steam

Is there a quick way to update steam from the command line?  I would prefer to update steam without a GUI running so it can be done in the background (headless).

Comment: I don't know the first thing about steam, but did you originally install it from source, or via a package from your OS?

Comment: Have you looked into steamcmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download something called [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Linux). It has great documentation on how to update all sorts of things (Games, Steam, etc.) What I don't get is why not just open the client and Update from there?

Comment: Okay, cool I'll have to check that out.  My system is built on a headless box and I don't want to manually install it, too much work / error prone ...

Comment: "What I don't get is why not just open the client and Update from there?"

One reason could be that people running PC Bangs/Internet Cafes may want to force an update on all their dozens of machines at once, possibly off-hours to avoid high bandwidth during business open hours.